# Is it possible to clean some code using gtk2hs?

Tags: haskell, boilerplate, gtk2hs

I'm starting a GUI with haskell and gtk2hs.
I've got a notebook widget and I want to switch pages with "F1, F2 ... F11" keys.

My working code is:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
  initGUI

  builder <- builderNew
  builderAddFromFile builder "M62.glade"

  window <- builderGetObject builder castToWindow "window1"
  notebook <- builderGetObject builder castToNotebook "notebook1"

  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F1" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 0
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F2" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 1
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F3" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 2
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F4" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 3
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F5" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 4
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F6" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 5
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F7" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 6
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F8" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 7
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F9" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 8
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F10" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 9
  window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do "F11" <- eventKeyName
                                            liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook 10

  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI
```

Is there betters and/or concises ways to do it?
I've tried to handle it out of the 'main' but then only "F1" works.
I don't see how to manage this boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do
    'F':n_ <- eventKeyName
    let (n, ""):_ = reads n_
    liftIO . notebookSetCurrentPage notebook $ n - 1
```

This is hopelessly partial: there are two partial pattern matches that can throw an exception. But that's okay, because that's what `tryEvent` is for. At time of writing, all other answers involve registering many event handlers, whereas this one registers only one. This should have a (slight) performance advantage.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I choose to use this solution for the registering fact, but can you give some documentation about the partial pattern matches? I don't understand them yet... :)

Comment: @grwp For sure. What would you like to know? Maybe you want to know what things they will *not* match, or...?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know much about gtk2hs, but using `forM_` to loop over the key indices should go a long way. Also, it seems events are a `MonadPlus`, so pattern match failure can be favorably replaced with `guard`.

```
forM_ [0..10] $ \i -> do
    let key = "F" ++ show (i + 1)
    window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do
        pressed <- eventKeyName
        guard (pressed == key)
        liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook i
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution I was trying to do! That works very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting the repeated part into a function, like this:

```
import Control.Monad
import Graphics.UI.Gtk


main = do
  initGUI

  builder <- builderNew
  builderAddFromFile builder "M62.glade"

  window <- builderGetObject builder castToWindow "window1"
  notebook <- builderGetObject builder castToNotebook "notebook1"

  -- Split the repeated code into a reusable function, like this
  let registerKeyPressEvent n =
    window `on` keyPressEvent $ tryEvent $ do
      pressed <- eventKeyName
      guard (pressed == ("F" ++ show (n + 1)))
      liftIO $ notebookSetCurrentPage notebook n
  -- Thanks to Tarmil for catching a bug in the code that used to be above.
  -- Tarmil got it right, so I'm borrowing his/her version.

  -- Then you can call it more than once
  registerKeyPressEvent  0
  registerKeyPressEvent  1
  registerKeyPressEvent  2
  registerKeyPressEvent  3
  registerKeyPressEvent  4
  registerKeyPressEvent  5
  registerKeyPressEvent  6
  registerKeyPressEvent  7
  registerKeyPressEvent  8
  registerKeyPressEvent  9
  registerKeyPressEvent 10

  -- But even that is too verbose.
  -- You can shorten it even further like this:
  mapM_ registerKeyPressEvent [0..10]
```

`mapM` is like `map`, except for monads. The type of `map` is:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

meaning that it takes a function and applies it to every element of a list, returning the result. The type of `mapM` is:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

meaning that it takes a monadic function (such as `registerKeyPressEvent`, function in the `IO` monad that creates the side effect of registering a key press event). `mapM` then executes this function once for every element in the list, and not only collects the results into a list, but collects the monadic actions into the resulting monad, meaning that the side effects from running `registerKeyPressEvent` 11 times are performed in order.

The final piece of the puzzle is that you might get a type error if you use `mapM`, because it assumes you care about the resulting list, and therefore returns `m [b]`. However, in this case, the type of main is `IO ()`, and `()` is not going to match up to `[b]`. You therefore want a slight variation on `mapM` that throws away the resulting list, only collecting the monadic actions:

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

This has the return type you're looking for.

Comment: Good explanation, a mistake though: `("F" ++ show (n + 1))` is not a pattern, you can't put it on the left-hand side of `<-`.

Comment: Oops! Give me a minute.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I took the liberty of borrowing your version. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: If I minded my code being borrowed, I wouldn't put it on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Explanations are very clear, I forget about the mapM_ magic, used once, sometimes... :)
But the 'window' and 'notebook' need to be parameters of the registerKeyPressEvent function as they are just in the the main.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've moved registerKeyPressEvent inside main where it belongs.